# Saving formCollections values to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

Hey guys I am having an issue with saving formCollection values to an array.

So I have a form that consists of radio buttons that I am trying to pass to an action.

The radio buttons look like:

```
<input id="Likelihood" name="Likelihood" type="radio" value="5" /><br/>

<input id="Priority" name="Priority" type="radio" value="5" /><br/>

<input id="Type" name="Type" type="radio" value="7" /><br/>
```

This is my method taking in the form:

```
public ActionResult TriageScore(TriVM tri, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string[] value = new string[formCollection.Count];
        foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
        {
            value[i] = formCollection[key];
        }
     }
```

So in the parameter the formCollection has an AllKeys value that has a length of 3.  The content is [0] Likelihood, [1] Priority, [2]Type.  When I store the values into the array, It only stores 7 from the last radio button (Type) and the rest are null.

I forgot to mention that Likelihood Type and Priority will not always be the name.  These names will change dynamically, so I cannot simply just refer to `name = Likelihood`.

Comment: you need to increment "i" in your foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to increment "i" in your foreach loop, like this

```
   public ActionResult TriageScore(TriVM tri, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            int i = 0;
            string[] value = new string[formCollection.Count];
            foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
            {
                value[i] = formCollection[key];
                i++;
            }
         }
```